# Python ctypes.c_int32 - conversion to TCL

Tags: python, tcl, ctypes

Wasn't sure about the best title for this one...

Anyway, I'm trying to convert some Python code to TCL and have the following snippet in Python:

```
ctypes.c_int32(x << c).value
```

Which returns: `-293412352`

I've written this in TCL as a simple expr:

```
expr {$x << $c}
```

But this returns: `162915344896`

In both cases, `x = 1272776132` and `c = 7`

Is there a way to format or convert the TCL value so it's represented the same as the Python value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on precisely what you want to do, which in turn depends on the wider context of the algorithm. Tcl uses a model of integers based on bignums (even though it usually uses smaller types for the implementation) which means that we need to reinterpret the value.

```
binary scan [binary format i [expr {$x << $c}]] i theResult
# theResult = -293412352
```

However, if you just want to mask the bits off and don't really want the sign changing, do this:

```
set theResult [expr {($x << $c) & 0xffffffff}]
# theResult = 4001554944
```

(All results checked with Tcl 8.5 and Tcl 8.6 on a 64-bit platform, but any variation on a 32-bit platform would be considered to be a *critical* bug; Tcl's fairly careful in its numeric code to create the illusion of numbers not having a finite number of bits available, except in the `binary` command — as used above — and in the `format` and `scan` commands, though not in a way that's useful here.)

Comment: If you don't need the conversion/masking, just use plain old `expr {$x << $c}` of course.

Comment: Awesome. The binary scan works great. The wider context is the python code is for a hashing algorithm (similar to MD5), which itself was ported from some javascript code. As the JS code is returning 32-bit integers, the python code was forced to return the same, and so the TCL code needs to do likewise.

Comment: @thor Hashing algorithms usually work fine with unsigned arithmetic, but that would definitely require careful testing. (You probably should do that anyway; the `tcltest` package is recommended, and comes with every Tcl installation.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is a bit-width issue. To hold the output of your TCL expression, you need a 64-bit integer, not a 32-bit integer.

```
# Wrong
In [7]: C.c_int32(x<<c)
Out[7]: c_int(-293412352)

# Correct
In [9]: C.c_int64(x<<c)
Out[9]: c_long(162915344896)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there some way to force 32-bit int in TCL then? The existing Python code (and values) is what I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: I would suggest masking the higher order bits with `($x<<$c)&0xffffffff`, but this does not fix the sign. It looks like Donal Fellows answer solves that problem.